# Is there a way consume Kafka Messages from windows to a file on the server through Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm able to write messages to a Kafka Topic, but I can't find the windows command to consume a message to a file through Kafka connect. Does anyone know the command?

This commang works fine to write messages, but looking for the command to consume messages and write to a file on the server.

```
./bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties etc/kafka/connect-file-source.properties etc/kafka/connect-file-sink.properties
```

Comment: So you have data in a Kafka topic, and you want to write it to a file? For that the FileSink will work (although is not recommended for Production use). If you are using this and it's not working, please can you post the config that you're using.